# DC-DC converter inductor current DC component

Tags: dc-dc-converter

How does the dc-dc converter (e.g. basic buck topology) ensure that for different load currents (considering CCM mode only), the DC component of the current through the inductor is auto-increased/decreased (auto-adjusted), while the "triangle" $$\int u dt$$ part remains unchanged for fixed output voltage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duty cycle for a buck converter is (to a first order) independent of load current (but not Vin) in steady state.  Consider the output L-C as a filter giving you the average voltage of the chopped input, providing a constant voltage output.

As load increases, the current in the inductor increases, but the duty cycle remains fixed.  The inductor current ramps up for Ton and down for Toff.

As the load increases, the output voltage drops temporarily.  During the on time the voltage across the inductor is Vin-Vout, so there are more volt-seconds across the inductor.

During the off time there is less voltage to discharge the inductor.  This causes the inductor current to increase until a new steady-state value is reached and the on and off time currents ramp amplitudes are again equal.  $$(Vin-Vout)*ton/L $$has to equal $$Vout*toff/L$$ for the discharge time.  No dependency on the load current.

If they are again equal, then the duty cycle must have returned to the original value, and the output voltage is again the average value of the chopped Vin.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter):
[image]

A control loop wrapped around all this will take out the IR drop errors and correct the output by changing the duty cycle slightly.

Answer (score 0):

The output voltage  ratio is divided to match the internal reference and the gain of this error difference controls the average current thru the inductor to minimize this DC error.  This can be done either on a cycle by cycle basis or averaged with dynamic performance tradeoffs.

A linear regulator changes the series impedance to maintain a constant impedance ratio with the load by regulating the effective Rce or RdsOn.  Consider also that an SMPS does the same but averaged over some period of the continuous ON-OFF switched path of current cycles, as the voltage ramps up and down in the inductor.  The average resistance of a switched resistor is Req=Ron/d for the d=%duty cycle and controlling this and the inductor impedance to maintain the demand of current.

If we consider the inductor has an instantaneous impedance is pure reactive but by alternating the direction of current with switches, it also transfers real power and has an average real resistance measured by the average Z= ΔV/ΔI from input to output.

When losses get too high at very light loads and low duty cycles of PWM, modern regulators automatically switch to PFM mode. A PWM only might only be 1% efficient at 0.2% load but with PFM might be > 60%. efficient with these light loads.